# How to fix tab key in VS Code to the code editor window only

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing code and I hit TAB I expect the typical 4 spaces to be inserted and the cursor to move.  In VS Code, if I hit TAB it takes me to the ... in the upper right of the application, tab again it goes to the Open Editors.  Its like TAB is jumping around the editor instead of tabbing into my document.

How does one fix that.  Or was a setting changed?

Comment: You can do a bit of digging in 1. ctrl+shift+p  2. Keyboard Shortcuts 3. Search for "Tab" with quotes on. 4. If there's a binding which is disturbing you, right-click and remove that key binding.  There can be multiple reasons but this may help you.

Answer (score 6):

At the bottom of the application, I noticed a Tabs move Focus was lit. I clicked it and it turned off. Not sure how it turned on or what turns it on, but if I click it off, tabs go back to normal.  Strange.

Comment: To turn on "Tab Move Focus", the default binding is ctrl+ m